Is "was dann damit geschieht" active or passive?

Wandeln Sie den aktiven Sätze ins Passiv um und umgekehrt, wenn möglich

Beim Export von Müll wird in der Regel nicht kontrolliert, was dann damit geschieht.


What type of sentence is was dann damit geschieht? is it active or passive?
In the answer for the above sentence, the second part was completely unaffected. I am trying to figure out why.

Obiously the task is to convert the main clause to passive. The main clause is not was dann damit geschieht but Beim Export von Müll wird in der Regel nicht kontrolliert, ...

Can you check your quoted task desciption? den aktiven Sätze seems to have wrong grammar case of the article and Aktiv-Sätze would be easier to understand than aktive Sätze.

"Was dann damit geschieht" is in active voice.
The verb "geschehen" is not transitive.
Therefore it does not have a passive form.

In German even intransitive verbs can have a passive voice. E.g. Es wird geschlafen. Most intransitive verbs are just picky with their accusative object anyways. E.g Es wird der Schlaf der Gerechten geschlafen. Such verbs are called unergative within the intransistive group. The verb geschehen is unaccusative on the other hand, that means it treats its subject like an accusative object. That's why you can't build a passive voice. It's semantically passive in active voice already.

The verb geschehen is a bit special because it's one of the few German verbs that does not have a passive voice. This is for semantic reasons, and the grammar reflects that.

It does not take an accusative object. So you can't build the werden-passive that turns the accusative object into the subject of the passive voice sentence.
It does not allow a static passive. Es ist geschehen. is Perfekt tense, not passive voice.
It does not allow a subjectless passive either. Es wird geschehen. is Futur I tense, not passive voice.
And it does not take a dative object either so you can't build the bekommen-passive that turns the dative object into the subject of the subject of the passive voice sentence.

So you can't turn yout example sentence further into passive voice. And when you turn the first part into active voice the second part stays the same because it's already active voice.
